# Scope of variables inside of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code sample that im trying to wrap my head around

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        test("load json", function () {

            length = 0; // length = 0

            $.getJSON("plugins/form.json", function (data) {
                length = data.fields.length; // length = 4
            });

            ok(length == 4, "length = " + length.toString()); // length = 0? wtf?
        });
    });
```

the 'length' variable does not persist when the $.getJSON runs.  I cant figure out if its because its asynchronous or because the variable is out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the getJSON method is running asynchronously, then the ok(... line will likely execute before the getJSON returns...thus length will always be 0...

could you not do this...

```
$.getJSON("plugins/form.json", function (data) {  
   var somelength = data.fields.length;  
   ok(somelength == 4, "length = " + somelength.tostring());  
});
```

that way it calls the ok function once the getJSON has returned with data...

Comment: That's completely right but not enough, the test runner needs to be paused and resumed, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665359/scope-of-variables-inside-of-javascript/2665383#2665383) and [example](http://jsbin.com/eyona3/)

Comment: I wasn't familiar with QUnit...+1 your answer...but mine is still providing an answer to why the code isn't working (hopefully!)...

Answer (score 2):

You should make an *asynchronous test*, and since you are using [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/), you can use the [`stop`](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/stop#timeout) method, make your assertions on the `getJSON` callback, and then resume the following tests:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    test("load json", function () {
        stop();

        $.getJSON("plugins/form.json", function (data) {
            var length = data.fields.length;
            ok(length == 4, "length == " + length);
            start(); // resume tests
        });
    });
});
```

Or you can use the [`asyncTest`](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/asyncTest#nameexpectedtest) method instead of `test`, which will implicitly make a call to `stop`:

```
//...
asyncTest("load json", function () {

    $.getJSON("plugins/form.json", function (data) {
        var length = data.fields.length;
        strictEqual(length, 4, "length"); 
        //...
        start(); // resume tests
    });
});
//...
```

Check a live example [here](http://jsbin.com/eyona3/) and give a look to the source code [here](http://jsbin.com/eyona3/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Its not because of scope issue, but because of this line run first

```
ok(length == 4, "length = " + length.toString());
```

before callback function from JSON

```
function (data) {
    length = data.fields.length; // length = 4
}
```

You need to put `ok(length == 4, "length = " + length.toString());` function inside callback function of `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be because it's asynchronous.

```
test("load json", function () {

     // executes first

     $.getJSON("plugins/form.json", function (data) {

         // executes last (that is, "sometime later")

     });

     // executes second

});
```

Also, you should declare the variable as `var length` the first time, unless you want it to be global.

Answer (score -1):

Try this - 
$(document).ready(function () {

```
var length = 0; // length = 0
    test("load json", function () {

        $.getJSON("plugins/form.json", function (data) {
            length = data.fields.length; // length = 4
        });

        ok(length == 4, "length = " + length.toString()); // length = 0? wtf?
    });
});
```